# Why I am getting the empty list while trying to fetch the query with the paramaterized generic

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I am trying to fetch the List of the Type  as depicted in the code below -:

```
    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongotemplate;

    @Override
    public <T> List<T> getDetails(Query query, Class<T> queryClass) {

        List<T>  list= mongotemplate.find(query, queryClass);

    return list;
    }

}
```

This repository is called from the service as-:

```
return messageSummaryImpl.getDetails(query, MessageSummaryDoc.class);
```

and the return Type of this function is `List<MessageSummaryDoc>`

As the result of this is an Empty list,This code works fine when i dont use the generic function or say by directly calling the repository function from the service itself
`(mongorepository.find(query,Classexample.class))`
Please suggest me what i am doing wrong.

PS-: please don't ask me why i am not calling the repository directly(As this is the project requirement).

Comment: why don't you check your _JPA_ logs and and see what query is being generated ?

Comment: Its simple - there are no entries matching your query. End of story ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you have no entires that matches query or your mongotemplate does something fancy with query.

You stated that if you do `(mongorepository.find(query,Classexample.class))` you got some data, but you are not using `mongorepository` in given code but `mongotemplate` so that is "false proof of concept"

Generics won't affect this issue by any means - they are gone on runtime anyway.